# Microservices: Implementing a Saga

Tags: java, microservices, saga

I ordered the book Microservices atterns by Chris Richardsson.

I am reading the chapter on Sagas now after I read through some other chapters and took quite some notes. So yes, I have not yet read it from A to Z. But I think it should be enough to dare on some actual playing around.

Until now, there are no concrete examples. Almost zero example code.

However, slowly I would like to begin to implement an own easy microservice.

But neither web-articles nor the book (although in my opinion this actually should) seem to give me enough information. I feel left alone a bit.

Foremost I would like to know how to implement a Saga. The book only mentions Eventuate Tram as a Saga implementation and a code example for events as well as states here

https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html

(This is the only actual code example I know so far from the author)

Eventuate Tram - a project by the book-author himself - again only implements `orchestration based sagas`. And so the book is also very              much weighted towards `orchestration` rather than `choreography`.

I would like to know with what libraries (without .NET !) I can implement a Saga. Is it possible with Spring (and some implementation of the outbox pattern), or by what else toolchain am I supposed to implement a very basic Saga myself?

Answer (score 1):

of course it's possible with spring, you can see sample implementation here: https://vinsguru.medium.com/choreography-saga-pattern-with-spring-boot-microservice-design-patterns-fb35a1802bee